# Android 7.0 - TabHost - have to click twice

Tags: android, tabs

I work on old Android project:
minSdkVersion 9,
targetSdkVersion 19

It uses TabHost (API 1) as a container for a tabbed window view. Since our clients got devices with Android 7.0 they have to click twice on every tab to fire onTabChanged(). I've searched the internet far and wide, but found nothing about this problem.

Is there any quicker solution then updating whole project to use TabLayout and ViewPager? It's quite big so it would be costly.

TabHost in xml:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_comarch" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

It has set Listener like this:

```
mListTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
```

which fires onTabChanged:

```
public void onTabChanged(String tabId)
```

but always after second click on the same tab.

Comment: If it's not mandatory to use TabHost, change tab to `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` with  `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`. It will make implementation very easy and your layout more flexible with custom behaviour.

Comment: Ended up converting whole code to TabLayout